# Finding general formula for a recursion function

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

If we have a recursion relation defined as $a_n = 3a_{n-1}+1$ with $a_1=1$ then find the general formula for $a_n$ in terms of $n$ with a(1) = 1.

So far I have:

$a_n = 3a_{n-2}+1+1 = 3a_{n-3}+1+1+1 = 3a_{n-4}+1+1+1+1$

I'm unsure of where to go from here to find the solution.

Comment: Do you notice a pattern for what $a(n)=3a(n-k)+1$'s looks like?

Comment: I see that it increases by one for each time n increases. I'm a little bit confused on how the 3a works in this.

Comment: Well, more specifically, there's a total of $k$ 1's. So you have $a(n)=3a(n-k)+k$. So if you know a specific $a(n-k)$, can you find $a(n)$?

Comment: $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 1 = 3(3a_{n-2} + 1) + 1 = 9a_{n-2} + 3 + 1$ wich is not what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry, my professor decided to teach us recursion the day before our final exam which contains recursion. I dont think I fully grasp how the 3a(n-1) works in this equation. Looking at the example in my notes I thought I would increase it by one, but it should be +3 for each recursion, right?

Comment: How about $a(n) = a(1) + 1 + (n-1)*1$

Comment: That would correct be IF the second equation you wrote was correct, wich is not, as I've stated in my previous comment. If I have your permission, I'd like to edit your post to make that equation correct.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$a_{n}+\frac 12=3\left(a_{n-1}+\frac 12\right).$$
So, letting $b_n=a_n+1/2$, we get 
$$b_n=3b_{n-1}.$$
Since $b_1=a_1+1/2=3/2$, we have $$b_n=\frac 32\cdot 3^{n-1}=\frac{3^n}{2}.$$
Hence, we have 
$$a_n=\frac{3^n}{2}-\frac 12=\frac{3^n-1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove by induction that:

$$a_n = \frac{3^n-1}{2}$$

For $n = 1$, we have $\frac{3^1-1}{2} = 1 = a_1$. So that's good so far.

Assume our formula holds for $1\leq k \leq n$. Then:

$$a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 1 = 3\frac{3^n-1}{2} + 1 = \frac{3^{n+1}-3+2}{2} = \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$$

Wich is what we wanted to prove.

($a_n = 1 + 3 + 9 + \ldots + 3^{n-1}$. This is called geometric series. You can find quite a lot of info about it).

Answer (score 1):

Inductions and guessing are good, but it's better to handle problems like this in a more fundamental way, i.e. using generating function. It's harder but in the long run it is an invaluable tool for recurrences and much more. So you got
$$
a_{n+1} = 3 a_n +1
$$
Define $G(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k$. Now multiply both sides of the equation by $z^k$ and sum over $k$. On the RHS you get $3 G(z) + \frac{1}{1-z}$. On LHS after a bit of algebra you get $\frac{G(z) - a_0}{z}$. Now after some rearrangement you get 
$$
G(z) = \frac{a_0}{1-3z} + \frac{z}{(1-3z)(1-z)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}-a_0}{1-3z} - \frac{1}{2(1-z)} =(\frac{1}{2}- a_0) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 3^k z^k  - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k
$$
Now all you need to do is combine coefficients to get the value of the $\text{n}^{\text{th}}$ term:
$$
a_n = \frac{(1-2 a_0)3^{n}-1}{2}
$$ 
If $a_0=0$, you get
$$
a_n = \frac{3^n -1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct method for solving problems of this kind. I'll give the general case and then apply it to this specific example.

Let our sequence be of the form $a_n = \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta$ for $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb{R}$, then by repeated substitution we obtain
\begin{align*}
 a_n &= \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta \\
        &= \alpha^2a_{n-2} + \alpha\beta + \beta\\
           &= \alpha^3a_{n-3} +  \alpha^2\beta + \alpha\beta + \beta\\
        &\;\,\vdots \\
        &= \alpha^{n-1}a_1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\beta\alpha^i
\end{align*}
so when $\alpha = 1$ then $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)\beta$ and when $\alpha\ne 1$ then we apply the formula for the geometric partial sum and obtain

$$ a_n = \alpha^{n-1}a_1 +\beta\frac{\alpha^{n-1} - 1}{\alpha - 1} $$

In our case $\alpha = 3, \beta = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$, so substituting these in and simplifying gives

$$ a_n = \frac{3^n - 1}{2} $$

The good thing about doing it this way is that you can instantly see not only which sequences converge, but also what their limit is. The sequence $a_n=\alpha a_{n-1} + \beta$ converges if and only if $|\alpha|<1$ and the limit is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\beta\alpha^i = \frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$$

This is because when $|\alpha|<1$ then $\alpha^{n-1}$ goes to $0$, killing the $\alpha^{n-1}a_1$ term, and it is the radius of convergence for the geometric series. So in particular your sequence diverges. I know convergence wasn't part of the question but it's useful to know!